# Problem with function template without <>

Tags: c++, templates

Is there anyway I can do this without writing `func2<int>();`

```
int func() { return 5; }

template<class T>
T func2() { return func(); }


int main()
{
    auto k = func2();
    //auto k = func2<int>();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `func2` a template? And are you using C++0x (I guess, since you are using `auto`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because the template argument can not be deduced. You need to specify it, how else would the compiler know what to substitute it with? `int`? `double`? A user-defined type?
**Edit**
If you're already using C++0x (I assume so because of `auto`), you can use the new trailing return type function style:

```
auto func2() -> decltype(func()) {
  return func();
}
```

`decltype(func())` would get the return type of `func`, without actually calling it.
**Edit2**
Okay, you don't even need the trailing return type, a simple `decltype` does the job too:

```
decltype(func()) func2() { return func(); }
```

The trailing return type is more useful for situations where the return depends on some or all of the parameters, and especially if they're templated. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523617/omit-return-type-in-c0x/4574567#4574567) for a nice explanation.

Comment: cant it look at the return type of func()?

Comment: No, since a conversion might be intentional. You can however let it deduce the return type from func, if you really want that.

Comment: will this: decltype(func()) run the function or just look at it:)?

Comment: @Merni: Like I said, "`decltype(func())` would get the return type of func, without actually calling it."

Comment: what about if func is a function inside a class, thats not possible is it, to write something like decltype(class_name.func())

Comment: @Merni: Not like that, but if the class provides a default constructor, you can do a little trickery: `decltype(ClassName().func())`. The class constructor won't even be called! But you still get the return type of the function.

Comment: For a different spelling of that last comment that does not require a default constructor: `decltype( static_cast<ClassName*>(0)->func())`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for something like that:

```
int func() { return 5; }

auto func2() -> decltype( func() )
{
  return func();
}

int main()
{
  auto k = func2();
}
```

However, I don't understand why you made `func2` a template, since you always want it to return an `int`. It could be useful if you wanted to cast the result of `func` to another type, but in this case you would need to specify explicitely the type you want as a return.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this. The compiler has no way of deducing the template argument since it does not consider the return type for that.

If you are willing to relent and use `int k` instead of `auto k` then you can use a “cheat” to achieve the same goal by returning a proxy object that has an implicit conversion to typename `T`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not able to deduce the template argument type from the return type you are assigning to. You are not giving any hint to the compiler what the return type could be. Therefore, any template argument types which cannot be deduced need to be explicitly specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this syntax with c++03 *if* you use `int` instead of `auto`:

```
int func() { return 5; }

template<class T> T func2() { return func(); }


struct Inference {
    template<typename T> operator T () { return func2<T>(); }
};

int main() {
  int k = Inference();
}
```

EDIT: nvm, `Konrad Rudolph`'s answer already said this.