# Return type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Omit return type in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523617/omit-return-type-in-c11)

In C++11 lambda can deduce their return type if the body consists of only a return statement.  A [proposal is the works](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#975) to remove this restriction, and apparently it's already working in GCC.

Is there a reason this couldn't be extended to all `auto` returning functions?
Has this extension already been proposed?

Comment: Lots of things has been discussed.  The standard committee now wants to see working prototype compilers before adding new features to the official language -- they got bitten pretty badly in the past on good ideas that turned out to have terrible specifications (function exception specifications, export templates).  So the thing to do is find someone willing to add the feature to g++, then it is likely to be standardized (if it's a clearly positive feature like this).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a reason this couldn't be extended to all auto returning functions?

Well, there's the fact that it wouldn't be possible unless the function was defined right there (not just a declaration). You'd lose the ability to forward declare such functions.

Also, functions don't return `auto`. The `auto` in front of a function definition is a purely syntactic thing to allow for *trailing* return types. And the only reason the return type is specified last is so that it can refer to the function's arguments (for template and `decltype` work, usually). The functions still do return a specific value.

Comment: Of course, for a function of any complexity but a single return statement, the compiler could pretty much take *return-expression* and use `decltype(return-expression)` and use that as the return type.  Only reason it isn't a mechanical transformation is that the return-value expression might involve local variables that aren't in scope for a trailing return type.

Comment: Another option would be a simple syntax for a function that computes an expression.  For example, instead of `inline auto min(T a, T b) -> decltype((a < b)? a : b) { return (a < b)? a : b; }`, something like `auto min(T a, T b) => ((a < b)? a : b);`, stripping out the repetition of the return expression as well as the return keyword and adding implicit `inline`.

Comment: Ack, I'm wrong.  See my edit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523617/omit-return-type-in-c11

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is a reason.

Namely, the name of a function is in scope inside a function, but not in the *trailing-return-type* specification.  Lambdas are exempt because they don't have names, although I think a variable being initialized from the lambda, typed by inference, is also in scope, so [they already suffer this problem even with the standard syntax](http://ideone.com/lUqOY) ([workaround](http://ideone.com/0MDAC)).

With the name of the function in scope, it's possible to construct an infinite circular type dependency.  e.g.

```
auto fact(int n)
{
    return (n > 0)? n*fact(n-1): 1;
}
```

In this case typing is consistent for several choices of return type... `int`, `long long`, `float`, and `double`, as well as `std::complex<double>`, etc.

No problem with *trailing-return-type*, the code is simply illegal:

```
auto fact(int n) -> decltype((n > 0)? n*fact(n-1): 1) /* unknown identifier fact */
```

In another example, it's inconsistent for any choice of return type:

```
auto f(int a)
{
    char r[sizeof(f(a))+1];
    return r;
}
```

What does your new-and-improved g++ do with this?

```
auto fact = [&](int n){ return (n > 0)? n*fact(n-1): 1; };
```

Comment: Look at `(n>0)?n*fact(n-1): 1`. The type of `1` is `int`, and therefore the type of the `?:` should, by default, be `int`. This should follow through into an attempt to infer the return type of `fact` as `int`. (This example is a bit funny, because of all the implicit conversions allowed between integral and numeric types.) Languages such as Haskell have no difficulty inferring the types of recursive functions. There is no fundamental reason why C++ couldn't allow the same - perhaps the compiler should try to select the inference which involves the fewest conversions.

Comment: @Aaron: That was only a simple example, it can get a lot uglier, e.g. with SFINAE or taking the address of the current function.

Comment: I don't doubt it would be difficult/impossible in many cases. Even Haskell's type inference breaks down occasionally. But, in day-to-day programming, it would be possible more often than it is not. Hopefully, a large subset of this will make it into the big compilers soon.

Comment: ... PS: I'm not suggesting I can write a suitable section for a standards document, it would be a minefield. So I think your comment on the question, @BenVoigt, is a good one. The committee has done all it can, it's time for the compiler vendors to get into an arms race and show us what's possible!